# jQuery detecting non-existent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that checks to see if an img tag is inside of a figure element with a class of "colorbox", and if it is, to add some additional styling to some elements. However, the function still runs even if there are no images in the colorbox figure and I don't know why.

My jQuery looks like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  if ($(".colorbox").has("img")) {
     ~code here~
  }
}
```

And here is the colorbox figure, clearly without an img element...

```
<figure class="colorbox">
  <ficaption>
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

So why would jQuery be picking up an element that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would do it this way:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.colorbox img').each(function(){
      var imageElement = $(this);
      // do whatever you want with this element !
  });
  // OR this way
  $('.colorbox').each(function(){
      var box = $(this);
      if( box.find('img').length ){
          // this means the parent colorBox has at least 1 img-Element 
      }

  });
}
```

and now to your problem:

```
$(".colorbox").has("images");
```

`$(".colorbox")` returns a **list** of elements if any

then you ask if the list `.has("img")` ? this means if one element in the list has an **img** element inside, then you get a **true** as a result of that *if-statement*, this is why your code doesn't work as expected

Comment: Thanks for the response, but ironically I want to apply jQuery to *other* elements if there is an img tag, not to the img itself.

Comment: to other elements? which elements ? inside the each-loop you can apply Jquery to any other elements you want, not only to that image.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I managed to figure it out, thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 4):

I'd prefer `find` function

```
var $img = $(".colorbox").find("img");

if ($img.length) { //exisst

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Has returns a new jquery subset. You'll want `if($(".colorbox").has("img").length)` to check if there's any img tags in there

Comment: [Docs](https://api.jquery.com/has/#has-contained) to support it: "Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .has() method constructs a new jQuery object from a subset of the matching elements. The supplied selector is tested against the descendants of the matching elements; the element will be included in the result if any of its descendant elements matches the selector."

Comment: It appears that using the .length method prevents the function from working under any circumstances, therefore the function won't fire off even if there is an img tag.

Comment: Here is a sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rxkbo9q3/4/) to show how the length works and what $(".colorbox").has("img").length outputs and what $(".colorbox").has("img") outputs.  Hope it helps show the difference.